# Laravel Bulk Insert Optimization

Tags: php, laravel, postgresql

I'm developing a system using Laravel where users can generate multiple QR codes based on the number that the user inputs in the input field.

I tested the system by generating 100 QR codes at a time and it took almost 2 minutes to finish the generation. What can I do to improve the speed of generation to be as fast as possible? Thank you!

##### `StoreQR` in Controller:

```
public function storeQR(Request $request)
{
    $numberOfDevices = (int) $request->input('number');
    if ($numberOfDevices <= 0) {
        return back()->withErrors(['number' => 'Please enter a valid number of devices.']);
    }

    for ($i = 0; $i < $numberOfDevices; $i++) {
        $deviceID = Str::random(8);

        // Create device data
        $devices[] = [
            'deviceId' => $deviceID,
        ];
    }

    GenerateQRJob::dispatch($devices);

    return to_route('devices.index');
}
```

##### `GenerateQRJob`

```
public function __construct($devices)
{
    $this->devices = $devices;
}

/**
 * Execute the job.
 */
public function handle(): void
{
    $devices = [];
    foreach ($this->devices as $device){
        // Generate QR code and path
        $qr = QrCode::format('png')
        ->size(285)
        ->generate(route('devices.qr', $device['deviceId']));
        $path = 'img/qr-codes/' . $device['deviceId'] . '.png';
        Storage::disk('public')->put($path, $qr);

        $devices[] = [
            'deviceId' => $device['deviceId'],
            'barcode' => $path
        ];
    }
    DB::table('devices')->insert($devices);
}
```

Comment: What is `QrCode`? is it an external package? Which one? do you know which part is taking a lot of time?

Comment: hi, yes. QrCode is package to generate QR code from SimpleSoftware.io. turns out the package itself is the one that taking a lot of time when generating QR Code

Comment: maybe reduce the size